# make the 3d cube to look like a 2d rectangle in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

How can I make a 3d cube with invisible walls but visible surface (the down and the inner surface which is on the ground) in unity 3D? I mean I want the 3d cube to look like a 2d rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing one of the Vector3 scale values (x, y or z) to a low number (0.001) will make it look like a 2d rectangle.

First example below is an unaltered cube, and the next is the same cube with the x scale value lowered to 0.001.

[image: unaltered cube]
[image: low x value cube]

*Note: this does not make the sides invisible*.

*Waning: This method is more resource consuming*. If you want to make the sides invisible, you could create your own cube using 6 2d squares (which you can do by going to the **Project Folder > Create > Sprites > Square**). Then making all of them invisible by disabling **Mesh Renderer** component on them (except for the one 2d rectangle you want to stay visible).